# Firefox SDK : Listen for a change in non addon specific about:config entry

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, listener, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to listen for changes to settings in firefox's about:config that the user could have changed while my addon is running. The settings in question are part of the browser and not created by my addon.

I can read and set them manually when the user has used my addon with no problems using the "preferences/service" module, but I want to be able to make the appropriate changes in my addon if the user has changed a setting in about config independently of my addon.

The "simple-prefs" module provides a listener but that is only for settings specific to your application, like "extension.myaddon.mypreference" where as the settings I need to watch are like "network.someoptionhere"

If someone could point me in the right direction as to how I would go about this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some XPCOM, namely [`nsIPrefService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/public/nsIPrefService.idl)/[`nsIPrefBranch`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/public/nsIPrefBranch.idl) (e.g. via [`Services.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm)). This is the same stuff that `preferences/service` and `simple-prefs` wraps.

Here is a full example:

```
const {Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
const {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});

function observe(subject, topic, data) {
    // instanceof actually also "casts" subject
    if (!(subject instanceof Ci.nsIPrefBranch)) {
        return;
    }
    console.error(subject.root, "has a value of", subject.getIntPref(""), "now");
}

var branch = Services.prefs.getBranch("network.http.max-connections")
branch.addObserver("", observe, false);

exports.onUnload = function() {
    // Need to remove our observer again! This isn't automatic and will leak
    // otherwise.
    branch.removeObserver("", observe);
};
```

Comment: Thank you nmaier that did the trick. I appreciate your help and time